# Search a column for values LIKE in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I searched but couldn't find what I was looking for, maybe I'm not looking for the right terms though.

I have a colum for SKUs and a Keyword column, the SKUs are formatted AA 12345, and the Keywords are just long lists of words, what I need to do is find any records where the numbers in the SKU match any part of the Keywords, I'm just not sure how to do this.  For example I'd like to remove the AA so that I'm looking for %12345% anywhere inside of the value of keywords, but I need to do it for every record.

I've tried a few variations of:

`SELECT *, Code AS C
FROM Prod
WHERE Keywords LIKE '%C%';`

but I get errors on all of them.  Can someone help?

Thank you.

EDIT: Okay, sorry about that, the question wasn't the clearest. I'll try to clarify;

The SKU column has values that have a 2 letter prefix in front of a varying amount of numbers such as,  AA 12345 or UN 98767865

The Keywords columns are full of information, but also include the SKU values, the problem here is that some of the keyword columns contain the SKU values of products that have entirely different records

I'm trying to find what columns contain the value of different records.

I hope that's more understandable.

EDIT EDIT: Here is some actual sample data

```
Code: AD 56409429
Keywords: 56409429, 409249, AD 56409429, AD-56409429, Advance 56409429, Nilfisk 56409429, Nilfisk Advance 56409429, spx56409429, 56409429M, 56409429G, 56409429H, ADV56409429, KNT56409429, Kent 56409429, AA 12345

Code: AA 12345
Keywords: AA 12345, 12345, Brush
```

I need to find all the records where an Errant Code value has found it's way into the Keywords, such as the first case above, so I need a query that would only return the first example

I'm really sorry my explanation is confusing, it's perhaps an extension of how confused I am trying to figure out how to do it. Imagine me sitting there with the site owner who added thousands of these extra sku numbers to their keywords and having them ask me to then remove them :/

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Why `'%C%'` and not `'%' + Code + '%'`?

Comment: You may be able to do something like this: `SELECT *, Code AS C FROM Prod WHERE Keywords LIKE '%' + Code + '%'`

Comment: @logixologist just syntax errors, I tried your second edit, and it's returning results I'm not looking for I'll try and edit the question so it makes more sense

Comment: Yes.. you cant put the c in like that. You need to just put code in but force a % on each side like I am showing in my comment.

Comment: @logixologist I see, I wasn't aware I couldn't do that

Comment: Yes please clarify the question. It seems like you are looking for keywords that match the value in `Code`

Comment: @logixologist I tried to clarify it, that is what I'm trying to do, but I'm trying to find values from Code that exist in Keywords of records that don't correspond to the record such as if code = aa 12345 then keywords will also have aa 12345, but I'm looking for the case where code = aa 12345 and keywords contains aa 12345 AND un 87654 (which would be another records Code)

Comment: @salty do the keywords have the letters and numbers? how are multiple keywords separated in that column?

Comment: @CSL I'll edit in an example, they're just separated by commas

Comment: @salty see the edit to my answer below it may help you

Comment: @salty I see your edit but why would the second record not need to be returned it has the Keyword 'Brush' which is not AA 12345. How would a logic based sql statement know that that product was in fact a Brush?

Comment: @CSL That's kind of what is tripping me up as well logically, but it doesn't need to be returned because it doesn't include the SKU of a different product in it, basically I just need to find all the keywords that have SKUs from products that don't belong in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all of your `SKU` values are in exactly the same format you can remove the 'AA' part using `SUBSTRING` and then use the result in the LIKE statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Prod WHERE Keywords LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(Code, 3,5) + '%'
```

Seeing as your SKU codes can be variable length the SUBSTRING statement above will have to changed to:

```
SELECT * FROM Prod WHERE Keywords LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(Code, 3, LEN(Code)) + '%'
```

This will remove the first 3 characters from your SKU code regardless of the number of digits it contains afterwards.

It is not entirely clear from your question whether or not the Keywords are in the format `AA 12345` or just `12345` but assuming they are and are comma separated. Then you can find all records where the code is in the keywords but there are OTHER keywords also by using this statement:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM Prod 
   WHERE Keywords LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(Code, 3, LEN(Code)) + '%'
     AND Keywords <> SUBSTRING(Code, 3, LEN(Code))
```

This statement basically says find me all records where SKU code is somewhere in the Keywords BUT also must not exactly match the Keywords contents, i.e. there must be other keywords in the data.

Ok based on your last revisions I think this will work - or at least get you along the road (I am assuming your Product table has a primary key of Id). Also this is most likely horribly inefficient but seeing as it sounds as if this is a one off tidy up it may not matter too much as long as it works (at least that is what I am hoping).

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.Id
  FROM PROD P
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      -- Get all unique SKU codes from Prod table
      SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(CODE, 3, LEN(CODE)) as Code FROM Prod
    ) C ON P.Keywords LIKE '%' + C.Code + '%'
    AND SUBSTRING(P.Code, 3, LEN(P.Code)) <> C.Code
```

The above statement joins a unique list of SKU codes (with the letter prefix removed) with every matching record via the join on the Keyword column. Note: This will result in duplicate product records being returned. Additionally the result-set is filtered so as to only return matching records where the SKU Code of the original Product record does not match a SKU code contained in the keywords column. 
The distinct then returns only a unique list of Product Id's that have a erroneous SKU code in the Keyword column (they have may have multiples).

Comment: I don't see anything in the question to warrant the second part of that `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Ellesedil, agreed but in fairness the specifics of the question has changed 3 times in the last hour!

Comment: @salty working a solution for you now it is a little more complex than I first thought

Comment: @salty ok see my latest revision hopefully that will get you someway there

Comment: @CSL thank you!  It doesn't do exactly what I'm trying for, but it's getting me close enough that I can add in an extra parameter for date added and find the results that I'm looking for!  Thank you for being so patient with this one!

Comment: Rather than `LEN(Code)` - which needs to obtain the length for every single row - why not just `255` or whatever the column is defined as?

Comment: @AaronBertrand good point - the question and my answer have been revised so much in the last hour I lost track of that

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Is `STUFF()` going to be faster than `SUBSTR()` in this case it also would not require a call to `LEN()`

Comment: @Hogan `STUFF` might be safer (e.g. from changes to the column), but I'd be surprised if it would be faster (and if so, that the difference would be tangible). It's also less intuitive syntax IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

`Stuff()` seems better suited here.... I would do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Prod WHERE 
Keywords LIKE '%' + STUFF(SKU,1,3,'') + '%'
```

This will work for both `AA 12345` and `UN 98767865` -- it replace the first 3 characters with blank.